# How to run a method after passing through a tag in the feature file?

Tags: java, automation, cucumber, bdd, gherkin

I have a scenario in my feature file that contains two tags

```
@tag1, @tag2
  Scenario: This is a test
    Given I open the website
    When I log in
    Then the account page is open
```

Now @tag is part of a cucumber serenity runner and this works in isolation (before the implementation of @tag2):

```
@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="...features/", glue = {".../steps"}, tags = {"@tag1"} )
public class Tag1Runner extends Hooks {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void startAppium() {
        AppiumServerController.startAppiumServer();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void stopAppium() {
        AppiumServerController.stopAppiumServer();
    }
```

Now what I also want to do is run @tag2, but this only runs after the test has been completed. This is because the method that occurs in @tag2 should not be part of the scenario to test, but should complete a clean up after the test has ran.

Now if I include the following method below, when I run the feature file as it is displayed above, nothing happens.

How can I implement @tag2 to work as mentioned?

```
public class Hooks{

    @After("@tag2")
    public void completeCleanUp() {

        //code to perform clean up...

    }
}
```

Comment: Try public class methods{

   
    @After("@tag2")
    public void completeCleanUp() {

        //code to perform clean up...

    }
}

Comment: @MrCas I triedyour method but no luck, it doesn't run the method

Comment: I have updated my code on how I have now implemented the tagged hook even though it's still not working

Comment: Hi, Bruce, have you imported cucumber.api.java.After? Is the tag1 still working? Could you try to write the tags in the feature without the comma ? What happens if you try to run the test on debug mode -is it just skipping the method or? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run an After hook after each scenario tagged with "@tag1" in your example, you should mark the After hook with "@tag1". For more information on tagged hooks, please refer to the [Cucumber documentation](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#tagged-hooks).